# Rails App Deploy to Heroku Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, deployment

I’m trying to deploy my first app from Github to Heroku. I press “Deploy branch” and get message:

> “Your app was successfully deployed”

But when I open the view, I see the following message instead of my app:

> “Application error. An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs
>   for details”

I’ve tried many things to fix it, but the result is still the same and can’t find what I’m doing wrong. How can I fix my deploy correctly and see my app up and running on Heroku?

Heroku build log:

https://gist.github.com/Evanto/4ce2afa5a9e75b7154727356d77737e1

Github branch I’m trying to deploy to Heroku:

https://github.com/Evanto/MovieApp/tree/heroku

https://movieapps.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You can accept the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your logs, it says the following:

> Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile

Heroku supports only pg as the database of choice, so you need to add the following line to your `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'pg'
```

## Edit:

No, you do need to need any username or password in your database.yml file for Heroku. Writing the following in the said file will work fine for you.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: project_name_development
production:
  <<: *default
  database: project_name_production
test:
  <<: *default
  database: project_name_test
```

Comment: Console logs are: https://gist.github.com/Evanto/a2000f8aa66511f41ab1a777be75814d

Comment: In case that you used another DB than 'pg' before you need to change also your config/database.yml file specify pg settings. after that deploy again, run heroku rake db:migrate

Comment: Yes, you need to change `config/database.yml` file as well, deploy your code, and run the following commands: `heroku run rake db:create`, and `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thank you, where should I get credentials (db name, login, pass) for database.yml?

Comment: @Evanto I just edited my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Gemfile

```
gem 'pg'
```

config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username : root
  password : root
  database: db_name

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

On terminal:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: On terminal run "heroku logs -t" and check the issue under logs.

Comment: Thank you! Where should I take username, pass and database name?

Comment: There are credentials in the data.heroku.com panel, but heroku manuals say "Do not copy and paste database credentials to a separate environment or into your application’s code."

Comment: Username  and password are for local environment. On heroku they will automatically use their creds.